# Firestarter device not ready when booting Ubuntu

Tags: firewall, iptables, ubuntu-11.10, firestarter

I am trying to get firestarter running on Ubuntu 11.10 and I am getting an error:

> Failed to start Firewall
>   The device eth1 is not ready.
>   Please check your network device settings and make sure your Internet connection is active

I have edited my */etc/default/isc-dchp-server* to show *INTERFACES="eht1"*

I am not sure where to go from here. Do i need to edit */etc/network/interfaces*?

Also I have both */etc/network* and */etc/networks* What is the difference?

ifconfig -a results:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxx  
      inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.xxx.xxx
      inet6 addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xx Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9646 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1739614 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:505743 (505.7 KB)
      Interrupt:18 Base address:0xa000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
      inet addr:10.0.10.2  Bcast:10.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::52e5:49ff:fe39:d40f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:26196 (26.1 KB)  TX bytes:6475 (6.4 KB)
      Interrupt:44 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

Comment: Please post an `/sbin/ifconfig -a`

Comment: How many NICs (network cards) you got? If you have only one you usually need to use eth0 and not eth1. Also your wrote *INTERFACES="**eht1**"*. I hope this is just a typo here...

Comment: @m0skit0 - I have 2 NICs. eth0 is external, and eth1 is internal. DHCP needs to hand out ips on eth1 (internal) so I configured it to listen on eht1 in the isc-dhcp-server file.

Comment: @Paul - I will post my ifconfig -a results when I get home this afternoon. Thank you for the help!

Comment: ifconfig -a results have been appended to original question. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when I had a bridge from eth0 to virbr0 (for kvm/qemu). So if anyone get a similar problem try disabling the bridge (in `/etc/network/interfaces`), restart network and try again. After adding rules you can re-enable the bridge.

Or just do not use Firestarter. It's a dead application and it seems like the problem is a bug in Firestarter.

For other GUI for firewall see:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/111/gui-for-iptables

Comment: I ended up not using Firestarter and just learned iptables command line. Works perfectly, of course. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can search string "Failed to start Firewall" in scripts, and find exactly was is attented.
In a lot of scripts under Linux, an error message can't be really relevant.
You need to find exactly which commmand / which line do this message: it's a good way to find what is attended. You need to see inside the system.
(answer edited under the pressure of an administrator here ;) )

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing right now. Could you edit it to explain a bit more about how this would work and what it would do to help?

Comment: thanks for the answer boup, but I don't quite get what you mean? Could you please elaborate?